# What is the relation and history of 'si' and 'sic'?

Tags: etymology, word-comparison, language-evolution, pronouns, particle

Lewis and Short tell me that [*sic*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=sic&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) comes from [*si*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=si&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) by adding the particle *-ce*.
I can understand *sice* wearing down to *sic*, but I do not quite understand how I am supposed to understand the meanings of the words.

The meanings of *si* ("if") and *sic* ("so") seem pretty far.
If I am interpreting those dictionary entries correctly, *si* is a form (locative, ablative, or something) of an extinct pronoun related to the Greek articles starting with *h-*.
Forms of pronouns fossilizing into adverbs or conjunctions or particles makes sense to me, but I am not sure if I understand things correctly.

Here are explicit questions whose answers would help wrap my head around the matter:

1. Do *si* and *sic* come from the same form of the same pronoun (one with added *-c(e)*) or is the similarity coincidental?
2. What did this form of the pronoun mean? I would like to make sense of how the meaning evolved to both *si* and *sic* of classical Latin. (If they come from different forms of the same pronoun, what did they mean?)
3. Does *-ce* have an effect on meaning other than emphasis?
4. How did *si* and *sic* get so different classical meanings if they come from the same source?

Feel free to answer any subset of the questions you like.
I can split the rest into a follow-up question once I know which way to continue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is de Vaan's entry for both forms:

[image]

By this account (which I think is uncontroversial), both forms come from the locative singular of the demonstrative *so- "this", with an added enclitic *-ke in the case of *sīc*. This enclitic is the same form that shows up as *-c*, *-ce* in demonstratives like *hi-c*, *huius-ce*, etc., as well as some other words like *nun-c*, *ce-do*; it seems to have had (redundantly in many of its uses) a general proximal deictic meaning such as "this, here, now".

The semantic starting point is "in this (case)". For *sīc*, the shift from "in this case" to "in this way, thus" seems easily understandable. For *sī*, the grammaticalization to a conditional presumably took place in contexts like "In this case, namely X, Y will happen" -> "If X, Y".